# Minecraft Skin Glitch

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Ever since minecraft.net net updated, I can't change my skin. I've used multiple websites like mincraftskins.com and novaskin.me but regardless, when I try applying any skin, it always brings me here:
[image]

Whenever I click on the "Profile management" button, it keeps me on the same page but with a different url. Nonetheless, the skin doesn't change.

Comment: See any other buttons?

Comment: That seems weird... When I do exactly the same, when scrolling down it views the skin I made with a "Change" or "Reset to default" button. Did you try to use another browser?

Answer (score 1):

I see a similar screen when applying a skin from a third-party website. Try scrolling down; you should see the new skin image there, with a button that says "Change".

If that fails, try downloading the skin from the site you are using, and re-uploading it from the Profile page on minecraft.net.